# RefineryCMS - Duplicate a page with page parts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I have created a page say 'tour' with few page parts in the admin. I want to make many more pages similar to the page created say 'tour1', 'tour2' etc. Is there a way to duplicate it than manually adding a page and its page part?

Hope am clear with my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicating Pages functionality doesn't currently exist in Refinery.  But it isn't that difficult to add, I've done something similar for a custom engine I made where 'Events' had page parts and I let an admin duplicate them.  In your case, just override the Pages controller and add a route/action for the copying.  You can then create a new Page and add the page parts by copying the attributes over from the desired Page's parts. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks Supalrish. Yeah, I got what you meant. I will give it a try.